# What should JavaScript class constructor return when it fails in promise-based way?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check value of passing parameters in constructor, then do something in a chainable promise-based way. However, I found if I use `throw Error` in constructor if it fails, I cannot `.catch` the error. How can I achieve this goal?

```
class Car {
  constructor(name = '', brand = '') {
    if (!name || !brand) {
      throw new Error('Initiate error');
    }
    this.name = name;
    this.brand = brand;
  }

  beep() {
    return Promise.resolve(`${this.brand}-${this.name}`);
  }
}

const audi = new Car('A8', 'Audi');
audi.beep()
  .then((val) => console.log(val))

const test = new Car();
test.beep()
  .then((val) => console.log(val))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error)); // This line didn't work, how can I get the error thrown by constructor?
```

Comment: Your constructor has nothing to do with the promise, so there's no reason `.catch` would know about it. The error is being thrown before you even call the `.beep` function. Calling `.catch` on a promise only catches errors that happen within the promise itself (i.e. never, seeing as your promise just immediately resolves).

Comment: @JoeClay If I use `return Promise.reject('Initiate error')` in the conditional expression, then it will be promise way. However, I will get `test.beep is not a function` because it will be a `Promise.reject` object.

Comment: I think you're fundamentally misunderstanding how promises work. I'll write an answer to explain.

Comment: Done! (If you saw the first version of the answer I posted, I'd recommend taking another look - I came up with a better solution)

Comment: @JoeClay I've seen the new version. I think this could be better than the first version! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `Promise.resolve` or `Promise.reject`, these are effectively just helper methods for creating a new Promise object that immediately resolves or rejects. There's no reason your error *should* get caught by the `.catch` handler - the error doesn't take place within the promise, so it has no way of knowing about it.

I'd recommend moving your error out of the constructor and create it when it's actually being checked (i.e. in `beep`):

```
class Car {
  constructor(name = '', brand = '') {
    this.name = name;
    this.brand = brand;
  }

  beep() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      if (!this.name || !this.brand) {
        reject(new Error('Initiate error'));
      }

      resolve();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Got it !! I think I should check values before `new Car` and make the constructor simply just assign values into `Car`. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: The `then` can simply return the string. It need not have to be a Promise object.

Comment: Yeah, my previous version of the answer was massively over complicating things (and came across as a little condescending in my opinion). This one makes more sense in my eyes.